# Add object to table containing List of other objects using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm adding an object to a table in the database, adding a `contact` of `MarketingContact` type. These are my model classes:

```
public class MarketingContact
    {
        public MarketingContact()
        {
            this.ContactTags = new List<ContactTag>();
        }

        public int id { get; set; }
       //..some other properties not complex properties...
        public virtual ICollection<ContactTag> ContactTags { get; set; }
    }
```

This is the ContactTag model:

```
 public class ContactTag
    {
        public ContactTag()
        {
            this.MarketingContacts = new List<MarketingContact>();
        }

        public int TagId { get; set; }
       //some other no complex properties...
        public virtual ICollection<MarketingContact> MarketingContacts { get; set; }
    }
```

And this is my `AddContact()` method in my controller:

```
 [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult AddContact(MarketingVM marketingContactVM)
        {            
            List<ContactTag> contactTags = new List<ContactTag>();
            for (int i = 0; i < marketingContactVM.MarketingContacts.Count; i++)
            {
                if (marketingContactVM.MarketingContacts[i].IsSelected==true)
                {
                    contactTags.Add(new ContactTag { Name = marketingContactVM.MarketingContacts[i].Name, TagId = marketingContactVM.MarketingContacts[i].TagId,
                    InfusionSoftId = marketingContactVM.MarketingContacts[i].InfusionSoftId});
                }
            }
            MarketingContact marketingContact = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<MarketingContact>(marketingContactVM);
            marketingContact.ContactTags = contactTags;                  
             context.MarketingContacts.Add(marketingContact);
             context.SaveChanges();          
            return Json(new { result = "success"}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

Note that in my controller action I'm making use of a ViewModel(`MarketingVM type`).
At the time that I save into the database the `MarketingContact` object is saved in the `MarketingContacts` table, but in the `ContactTags` table new rows are created depending on what the `ContactTags ICollection` that belong to `marketingContact` contains, and I'm just selecting from `ContactTags`, the rows are already there, I don't need more rows with same values added in `ContactTags` table, why is this happening? At the moment I save the object into the database the `marketingContact` object contains a `ContactTags` collection with fields existing in the `ContactTags` table, including the correct `TagId` values, but instead of just relate them to that row in the `MarketingContacs` table it create new rows in the `ContactTags` table with the same values except for the `TagId`(it generates a new value) therefore the values are duplicated everytime in the `ContactTags` table and I don't need that. What would I need to change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that when you call

```
context.MarketingContacts.Add(marketingContact);
```

EF iterates the `ContactTags` collection and marks each object which is not currently tracked by (loaded in, attached to) context as new.

Since you know they are existing entities, you have to tell that to EF. One way to do that is to attach them to the context (which will mark them as `Unchanged`) before adding the main entity.

For instance, you can change

```
contactTags.Add(new ContactTag { Name = marketingContactVM.MarketingContacts[i].Name, TagId = marketingContactVM.MarketingContacts[i].TagId,
InfusionSoftId = marketingContactVM.MarketingContacts[i].InfusionSoftId});
```

to

```
// Note: setting just TagId would be enough
var contactTag = new ContactTag { Name = marketingContactVM.MarketingContacts[i].Name, TagId = marketingContactVM.MarketingContacts[i].TagId,
InfusionSoftId = marketingContactVM.MarketingContacts[i].InfusionSoftId};
contactTags.Add(contactTag);
// the next line will give you the desired behavior
context.ContactTags.Attach(contactTag);
```